# std::hash with a pointer and a byte size

Tags: c++, hash, stdhash

I've got a variable size binary data blob that is accessible through a `std::byte` pointer and a byte size. Is there a way to call `std::hash` on it? (I can't find any example for this)

Comment: Short answer: Nope.  Hashing of containers is left to the programmer as there is no one good way to do it.

Comment: `std::hash<std::string_view>` would be my best bet

Comment: [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/container_hash/doc/html/hash.html) has a library that does this

Comment: [boost::hash_range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_ran_idm46563411660048)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example based on my comment:

```cpp
#include <span>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

using bytes = std::span<const std::byte>;

template <>
struct std::hash<bytes>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const bytes& x) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>{}({reinterpret_cast<const char*>(x.data()), x.size()});
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto integers = std::array { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto doubles = std::array { 1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.0 };
    std::string string = "A string";
    
    auto hash = std::hash<bytes>{};

    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << hash(std::as_bytes(std::span(integers))) << "\n";
    std::cout << hash(std::as_bytes(std::span(doubles))) << "\n";
    std::cout << hash(std::as_bytes(std::span(string))) << "\n";
}
```

```
5ae7ce2c85367f67
42515290ba6efcdb
d760fec69e30b9e1
```

Of course, I used `std::span`, but you could use anything else (e.g. `std::pair<const std::byte*, std::size_t>`).

Alternatively, you could use MurmurHash (I believe that's what libstdc++ uses internally anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you have to create a custom hash function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, size_t N>
struct std::hash<std::array<T, N>> {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<T, N>& data) const noexcept {
        std::size_t value = data.size();
        for (auto byte : data) {
            value = std::hash<std::byte>{}(byte) + (value << 6) + (value >> 2);
            // value = value * 31 + std::hash<std::byte>{}(byte);
        }
        return value;
    }
};

template<>
struct std::hash<std::byte*> {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::byte *ptr, std::size_t n) const noexcept {
        std::size_t value = n;
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            value = value * 31 + std::hash<std::byte>{}(ptr[i]);
        return value;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    std::array<std::byte, 4> bytes{std::byte{0}, std::byte{1}, std::byte{2}, std::byte{3}};
    std::cout << std::hash<std::array<std::byte, 4>>{}(bytes) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hash<std::byte*>{}(bytes.data(), bytes.size()) << std::endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3695110
3695110
```

The types can be adjusted as necessary for your use case.

Edit: I added an alternative hash combiner (that is commented out) that in theory may produce better results.

Edit2: Added additional hash functor that takes a pointer and size.

Comment: Your example does not address a variable-size binary blob, but could be adapted to address it.

Comment: @moala You are right, I missed the target. I added another hash functor that takes a pointer and size as indicated by the OP.

Comment: It's not clear why you use specialization of `std::hash<std::byte*>`. The implementation doesn't satisfy [Hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash) requirements and can't be used where such requirement is expected (e.g. in unordered containers).